# How do I get children count in Strapi's one-to-many relation using GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, strapi

Lets say I have the following GraphQL query:

```
query {
  shops(id: 1) {
    id
    name
    products {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

How do I get the count of `products`? (for pagination purpose)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I overlooked at the issues on github. Apparently its [not yet supported](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/4808#issuecomment-568482004)

Answer (score 0):

For REST API, you can use query param to get children row count
https://test-id.herokuapp.com/childrentable/count?parentable.id=1